# How to print this value in java..Struggling for several hours

Tags: java

Struggling for hrs on how to print any one of this value in java

```
double s = 123456789123456789.988;
double r = 123456789123456789.9889012213;
double q = 123456789123456789.988901221344221;
```

I tried all the methods in java but nothing works.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: double s = 123456789123456789.988;
            System.out.println(String.format("%.8f", s));
            System.out.print(new BigDecimal("123456789123456789.987654").toString());
            System.out.println(String.format("%.1f", s));
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(s));
            System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(s)+"");
            System.out.println(String.format("%.10f", s));
            System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.#######################").format( s));

Comment: Double.toString(s) prints 1.23456789123456784E17

Comment: Stop posting code in the comments section, if the above information is relevant then add it directly to the question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67507618/edit) it.

Comment: Sure. @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) has from 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision. Your numbers have 21, 28, and 33 digits, so they get **truncated**.

Use `BigDecimal` created from a String to get the desired precision:

```java
BigDecimal s = new BigDecimal("123456789123456789.988");
BigDecimal r = new BigDecimal("123456789123456789.9889012213");
BigDecimal q = new BigDecimal("123456789123456789.988901221344221");
```

Note that it is *impossible* for a `double` to store those values. To see the nearest numbers that a `double` can store, try this:

```java
double value = 123456789123456789.988;
double lower = Math.nextDown(value);
double higher = Math.nextUp(value);
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(lower));  // 123456789123456768
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(value));  // 123456789123456784
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(higher)); // 123456789123456800
```

As you can see, even the smallest possible increase in value, is still an increase of 16, so it's not even close to be able to handle the fractional digits.

Answer (score 1):

Double values are great to do super-fast operations, but not so nice to display, you'll get nicer results with BigDecimal, plus, you still can get the double value from BigDecimal, so you'll get the best of the two worlds:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

BigDecimal s = new BigDecimal("123456789123456789.988");

// Print it correctly:
System.out.println( s );
// prints 123456789123456789.988

// Get its double value to do some super fast operation:
double doubleValue = s.doubleValue();
```

Comment: But the problem is i am getting a value in double primitive type which i need to print...Printing BigDecimal would work...But i have a double primitive value which needs to be printed

Comment: calling BigDecimal(double value) looses the precision and decimal values...so it cannot be used

Comment: According to [the java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/text/DecimalFormat.html), no precision is lost

Comment: May be..But run the program..precision is lost when doing BigDecimal(double primitive) and not talking about string value

Comment: What i am trying is reverse to your code..you are converting string to double..But what i am in need of is double to print as string value

Comment: Check the documentation, the problem is how you are conceiving your `double` value, this is why BigDecimal also provides the String constructor which is safer for your needs

Comment: The core of the problem is to realize that there is no such a `double` value as `123456789123456789.988`, that does not exist in java, even if you can write it on the code, once the data is at the VM, if you use `double` the real value will be an approximation. The other constructors provided by BigDecimal are available so you can use the best one which may adapt to your case.

Comment: Are you possibly using this to represent money? If so, that's a different problem

Comment: How do you say there is no such a double value..I am getting as an output from an API....Are your sure? Against which proof you are saying it is not a proper value?

Comment: I just need to print the value in logger or system out to see the results from the API.

Comment: I wrote: "there is no such a `double` value as 123456789123456789.988", because that's not the value that java stores at the VM. The VM stores an approximation of that value.

Comment: So you mean to say the double value holds cannot be printed or an invalid value ...

Comment: I don't think it is an invalid value but a valid value with long precision

Comment: I mean that if you really want to use `double` instead BigDecimal you should read some intro article to understand the basics of `double`. Floating-point based data types are tricky and not as simple as they seem at a first sight.

Comment: To sum it up, such huge precision values cannot be stored in `double` variables without any loss.
When you create it `double s = (...)`, the number is already approximated.
That means, if you receive such values, the precision is already lost, nothing will let you get it back.
That's why the answer suggests to use `BigDecimal` in the first place, instead of `double`.

Comment: Possibly you need to get a background of what the double type is. Here's a [nice article](https://arator.fi/en/a-brief-introduction-to-ieee-754-standard-for-float-representation/). Note: the article talks about float but in java, both float and double are implemented using IEEE 754.